# Using a Service to take photos and record video

Tags: android, android-service, video-recording

I'm using a service to take a background photo and then switch to recording a video. When switching to the mediarecorder I always get the error:

```
08-10 09:09:06.999 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense E/MediaRecorderJNI: Application lost the surface
08-10 09:09:06.999 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense D/RecorderService: invalid preview surface
08-10 09:09:06.999 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense W/System.err: java.io.IOException: invalid preview surface
08-10 09:09:06.999 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
08-10 09:09:06.999 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:582)
08-10 09:09:07.009 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense W/System.err:     at quantum_soft.com.vidsense.RecorderService.startRecording(RecorderService.java:78)
08-10 09:09:07.009 15263-15263/quantum_soft.com.vidsense W/System.err:     at quantum_soft.com.vidsense.RecorderService$1.onPictureTaken(RecorderService.java:39)
```

The service is able to take a photo OR record a video but I cant get it to do one after the other without losing the surface. I have tried all sorts of combinations of releasing the camera, preview etc but no luck so far.

My service is:

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private static Camera mServiceCamera;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        mSurfaceView = MainActivity.mSurfaceView;
        mSurfaceHolder = MainActivity.mSurfaceHolder;

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                startRecording();
            }
        };
        takePhoto();
    }

    public void takePhoto(){

        mServiceCamera = getCameraInstance();
        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mServiceCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }
    public boolean startRecording(){

        showLog("Recording Started");
        releaseCamera();
        mServiceCamera=getCameraInstance();

        try {

            mServiceCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/video.mp4");
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();

            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
        return c;
    }
    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mServiceCamera != null){
            mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mServiceCamera.release();
            mServiceCamera = null;
        }
    }
    public void showMsg(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d("VidTest", msg);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my main is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Recorder";
    public static SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    public static SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    public static SurfaceView mSurfaceView2;
    public static SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard", "VidTest");
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/VidTest/", "vids");
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                showMsg("Failed to create directories");
                finish();
            }
        }

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartService);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showMsg("Moitoring service started");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecorderService.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startService(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopService);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecorderService.class));
            }
        });
   }
    public void showMsg(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d("VidSense", msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe create 2 surfaces in your view and switch between them?

Comment: I've tried that but still fails. If I take the startRecording(); out of the picture callback function and place it directly in the service onCreate it then works and doesn't lose the surface. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: I've added surfaceholder callback to the service intent now so I can monitor the surface created in the Main activity. Within a second or 2 of the service starting the Main surface is destroyed. However it seems to exist long enough for the camera to take one photo or start one video.

Is there a way to keep the original surface 'alive' even though the activity closes? The whole point of this app is to be able to take videos and photos with the screen off, hence the use of a service.